Cannot setup the OBD2 VW Golf km4 2003 communication
Update: I finally got small step forward. I have 4 different serial cables for obd and one of those responds for AT codes but when I try to get supported PID with 0100 it returns
SEARCHING... UNABLE TO CONNECT.
I am working on developing a custom app to access car data. I started with a Nexas BLE OBD adapter, which works seamlessly with the CarScanner app on my iPhone. Using the nRF Scan app, I was able to find the necessary UUIDs to interface with the adapter. However, when attempting to connect from my laptop via BLE, all AT or PID commands return the same unchanging response. Frustrated by these persistent issues over two days, and suspecting that my MacBook might be contributing to the problem, I switched my setup to a Raspberry Pi 4. I also switched from a BLE adapter to a wired connection.
I also heard that my golf mk4 2003 doesn't have CAN bus for OBD communication and Kline protocol is implemented there. But from what I found there should be no difference when sending initialization codes.
Any help or advice very appreciated!!!!
This is my code for connection to OBD over BLE
const initializeButton = document.querySelector("#initializeOBD");
const status = document.querySelector("#status");
const responses = document.querySelector("#responses");

const OBD_SERVICE_UUID = "49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455";
const OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "49535343-6daa-4d02-abf6-19569aca69fe";
const OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID1 = "49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318";
const OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID2 = "49535343-4c8a-39b3-2f49-511cff073b7e";
const initializationCommands = [
    "ATZ\r",
    "ATL0\r",
    "ATE1\r",
    "ATH1\r",
    "ATAT1\r",
    "ATSTFF\r",
    "ATDP\r",
    "ATDP\r",
];

initializeButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    try {
        const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            filters: [{ namePrefix: "NEXAS" }],
            optionalServices: [
                OBD_SERVICE_UUID,
                OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID1,
                OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID2,
            ],
        });

        status.textContent = "Connecting to device...";
        const server = await device.gatt.connect();
        status.textContent = "Connected. Initializing...";
        const service = await server.getPrimaryService(OBD_SERVICE_UUID);
        const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(
            OBD_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID
        );

        for (const command of initializationCommands) {
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>Sending command: ${command.trim()}</div>`;
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            await characteristic.writeValue(encoder.encode(command));
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            const value = await characteristic.readValue();
            const hexString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(value.buffer))
                .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
                .join("");
            const bitArray = hexString
                .split("")
                .map((hexDigit) =>
                    parseInt(hexDigit, 16).toString(2).padStart(4, "0")
                )
                .join("");
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>Response (hex): ${hexString}</div>`;
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>Response (bit array): ${bitArray}</div>`;
        }

        responses.innerHTML += `<div>Initialization complete. Listening for RPM...</div>`;
        setInterval(async () => {
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            await characteristic.writeValue(encoder.encode("0100"));
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
            const value = await characteristic.readValue();
            const hexString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(value.buffer))
                .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
                .join("");
            const bitArray = hexString
                .split("")
                .map((hexDigit) =>
                    parseInt(hexDigit, 16).toString(2).padStart(4, "0")
                )
                .join("");
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>0100 Response (hex): ${hexString}</div>`;
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>0100 Response (bit array): ${bitArray}</div>`;
            await characteristic.writeValue(encoder.encode("0170"));
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
            const value = await characteristic.readValue();
            const hexString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(value.buffer))
                .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
                .join("");
            const bitArray = hexString
                .split("")
                .map((hexDigit) =>
                    parseInt(hexDigit, 16).toString(2).padStart(4, "0")
                )
                .join("");
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>0100 Response (hex): ${hexString}</div>`;
            responses.innerHTML += `<div>0100 Response (bit array): ${bitArray}</div>`;
        }, 2000);
    } catch (error) {
        status.textContent = "Failed to connect or test: " + error.message;
    }
});


And the output:
Initialize OBD
Connected. Initializing...
Responses:
Sending command: ATZ
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATL0
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATE1
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATH1
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATAT1
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATSTFF
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATDP
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Sending command: ATDP
Response (hex): 001800180000004800
Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000
Initialization complete. Listening for RPM...
0100 Response (hex): 001800180000004800
0100 Response (bit array): 000000000001100000000000000110000000000000000000000000000100100000000000

On the Raspberry Pi, I used Python and the obd library instead of JavaScript. The USB device was recognized at /dev/ttyUSB0. Despite various attempts, including adjusting baud rates and protocols through a loop in my Python script, I couldn't establish a connection to the car:
import obd
obd.logger.setLevel(obd.logging.DEBUG)  # enables all debug information

baudrates = ['38400', '9600', '230400', '115200', '57600', '19200']
for i in range(1, 7):
    for item in baudrates:
        connection = obd.OBD(portstr="/dev/ttyUSB0", protocol=i, baudrate=item)
        cmd = obd.commands.SPEED  # select an OBD command (sensor)
        response = connection.query(cmd)  # send the command, and parse the response
        print(response.value)

And some portion of the output:
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
[obd.obd] Explicit port defined
[obd.elm327] Initializing ELM327: PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0 BAUD=19200 PROTOCOL=6
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] wait: 1 seconds
[obd.elm327] Failed to read port
[obd.elm327] read: b''
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATE0\r'
[obd.elm327] Failed to read port
[obd.elm327] read: b''
[obd.elm327] closing port
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] ATE0 did not return 'OK'
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] Query failed, no connection available
None

The outputs consistently showed failures to read from the port, indicating no successful communication could be established. I also tried the simpler connection = obd.OBD() without specifying parameters, but faced the same issue. I expected that switching to a more reliable hardware setup and direct scripting approach would overcome the problems faced on the MacBook and allow successful data reading from the car's OBD system. Any advice or help to resolve these connectivity issues would be highly appreciated.

It's a bit tough to provide an answer, since many things can go wrong here. The BLE problem looks like you're at least reading from the wrong characteristic.
If I were you, I'd try the wired solution first. The usual bitrate for serial adapters is 115200. Use picocom (or another serial terminal program) and try to establish a communication first. Only afterwards, try with your own program.

@DrMickeyLauer Thanks for your reply!
At the end, I dropped BLE and found an OBD cable that works.
